# ASPX Security settings complicated

Tags: iis-6

Have an app on server ion.  It calls a webservice on server2.  Endpoint of that service is to write a pdf file on server3.

As a developer in dev on my laptop it works.  As a deployed app it fails on the write.

IIS6, Windows 2003 servers as well as VS2008

AppPool Identity as network service will not write the file.  If I use a "fake" user in AD the app pulls no data and fails to start up properly.

Any ideas?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the credentials that are running the app on server2 does not have write permissions to server3 (assuming server2 uses a UNC path to write to the filesystem on server3).

The user account that runs the IIS Application Pool (or however credentials are assigned to your app(s)) on Server2 will need write access to the share/UNCpath on server3; generally this means you cant use NetworkService.

If you change the user account in IIS on server2, you'll need to take into account all the implied permissions that the existing user account (assuming NetworkService) has on server2.
Including Filesystem, Registry, Metabase, etc permissions; the list could be very long and complicated or short and irrelevant (depending on your implementation on servers1/server2/server3).

For all my implementations, we use AD User accounts that are designated as Service Accounts; with extremely limited permissions on the servers, each App would have its own Service Account, and any touch-points would require explicit permissions applied. Thus, an account would be setup for the app on Server2 and the explicit permissions would be configured on Server2 to run the app, and the UNC path/share and NTFS permissions on Server3 would be applied explicitly for the file transfer.

Hope this helps.